# Firefox downloads text/plain instead of showing it

Tags: php, http, firefox, browser

I have a plain text page with some binary data (most data is text) in it like `"\003"` etc. I set the Content-Type header to text/plain and set the X-Content-Type-Options to nosniff. This stops Google Chrome and Internet Explorer from downloading the page and are instead showing it. But firefox for some reason decides that the page needs to be downloaded.

```php
header("content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
header("X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff");
header("Content-Disposition: inline");
```

What header has to be added to stop firefox from downloading a page and instead showing it?

EDIT:

I've tried Content-Disposition: inline

An example: http://nnmm.nl/?5eT0D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by setting the following headers:

```
header("content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; imeanit=yes");
header("X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a more complete test case?  I wasn't able to reproduce this problem in Firefox 29 using a sample PHP file with the same two headers and "\003" included in the output.

Update: Firefox does not support X-Content-Type-Options, though there is a long-standing request in [bug 471020](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=471020) and some work started on it last year.  As far as I know, until that bug is fixed there is no way to override Content-Type sniffing for text/plain files in Firefox.

What do you expect the browser to display for the non-printable characters in the document?  Can you get the results you want by stripping out the control characters on the server before sending the document to the browser?

Comment: http://nnmm.nl/?5eT0D is a great example. Just look at the response headers and what firefox tries to do with them.

Comment: One option could be to echo the whole content by PHP

Comment: I am already echoing the content as is with those headers. I'm not adding or removing any headers other then those three.